# How to process sockets

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio

I have to process data received from two sockets. Consider the following schema:

```
struct Session {
     Session() { /*...*/ }
     void process() {
          while (socket->recv()) {/*...*/}
     }
private:
     Socket* socket;
};

struct SessionWrapper {
     SessionWrapper() { /*...*/ }
     Command cmd;
     Session s{/*..*/};
     void process() {
          while ((cmd = socket->recv()) != Stop) {
               if (cmd == StartSession) {
                    s.process();
               } else if (cms == StopSession) {
                    // ...
                    break;
               }
          }
     }
private:
     SocketCmd* socket;
};

int main() {
     SessionWrapper w{/*...*/};
     w.process();
}
```

The problem is that when `Start` is received from the socket in `SessionWrapper`, the loop responsible of processing the socket in the nested `Session` starts too. It also means that now there will be no way to process any StopSession (or other commands) coming from the SessionWrapper.

How would you elegantly solve this problem in C++11 by using two different classes as above (note that socket members are deliberately private to enforce encapsulation) and without using coroutines and multiple threads?

It's possible to use boost if it can help to obtain a good design.

Comment: Why the pointers? Are both classes sharing the same socket?

Comment: @DanielKO: sockets are of different types, they do not share the same socket. they are pointers, but they could not be, I don't think it's important (this is why I put the /*...*/ in the constructor, assume they are created there somehow)

Comment: Why are you calling `process()` recursively? It doesn't make sense. It doesn't make sense to even have an instance of the SessionWrapper class until you receive a start-session command. This is just a code structure problem.

Comment: It seems you just need an event loop. Boost.asio has one built-in for working with sockets; often libraries and frameworks provide their own, because that's how you build most interactive applications.

Answer (score 1):

You just want to process the `Session` asynchronously.

Boost Asio is often employed for asynchronous IO in C++. In this case you'd need some way to stop the session too (it's not exactly clear from the picture).

If you describe better *what you are trying achieve* (not *how*) I might be be more specific